# Using Wild Cards in Powershell variables

Tags: powershell, variables, wildcard

I have a folder that has weekly reports. Each report has the date of creation in the name example "report-A_2_05_19.pdf", "report-B_2_05_19.pdf", etc. I would like to create variables for these but since the date changes in the name of the reports each week I was trying to do this:

```
$rA = "c:\reports\report-A*.pdf"
$rb = "C:\reports\report-B*.pdf
```

When I do this and try to open the report using the wild cards it just prints to the screen:

> c:\reports\report-A*.pdf

```
$pw = Get-Content C:\MailPW.txt | ConvertTo-SecureString
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential name@domain.com, $pw
Send-MailMessage -To name@domain.com -from name@domain.com -Subject "Attachments" -Body "Attachments." -attachments $rA, $rB -Smtpserver mail.domain.com -UseSsl -credential $cred
```

Comment: See [ask]. [Edit] the question and show your [mcve] and some example output showing the problem.

Comment: I am confused by the question.Like where do you use the variables `$rA` and `$rb`

Comment: $pw = Get-Content C:\MailPW.txt | ConvertTo-SecureString;$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential name@domain.com, $pw;
Send-MailMessage -To name@domain.com -from name@domain.com -Subject "Attachments" -Body "Attachments." -attachments $rA, $rB -Smtpserver mail.domain.com -UseSsl -credential $cred;

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the Docs for [`Send-MailMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-6)  you will see that `-Attachments` does **not** support wildcards

> Type: String[]
>
> Aliases:  PsPath
>
> Position: Named
>
> Default value:    None
>
> Accept pipeline input:    True (ByValue)
>
> Accept wildcard characters:   **False**

So what you could do instead is incorporate [`Resolve-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/resolve-path?view=powershell-6) which does extrapolate paths from wildcards strings.

```
Send-MailMessage .... -attachments (Resolve-Path $rA, $rB).Path
```

Beware though that this could match more than you intended. You might need to validate the results before you attach the files.

---

I would also recommend [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-6) when provided large amounts of parameters and values.

```
$sendMailMessageParameters = @{
    To          = "name@domain.com"
    from        = "name@domain.com" 
    Subject     = "Attachments" 
    Body        = "Attachments." 
    attachments = (Resolve-Path $rA, $rB).Path
    Smtpserver  = "mail.domain.com "
    UseSsl      = $true
    credential  = $cred
}

Send-MailMessage @sendMailMessageParameters
```

Comment: Actually I ended up not using the Variables and just used the file path of the report in the -attachments with the wild card and that worked. My issue is not with the send-mailmessage but trying to get a wildcard to work in a variable.

Comment: @irishombian I don't understand then. Do you want PowerShell to interpret your _string_ as a file path outright? You need to tell PowerShell how to deal with that. `Get-Item` would also work